# How to execute sql server stored procedure by using json?

Tags: asp.net, sql, jquery

Iam creating form for point of sale for resturaunt management system in Asp.net,I have two section one is
Category like which have buttons like Drinks,Pizza etc and 2nd section is of Item which are sub menus of Category like if you click on Drink it should open sub menus Pepsi,Coke,Mirinda etc from sql server table.

i have created run time buttons of category,now i want to use json to execute stored procedure
to show sub menus in item on the click of category
Buttons.please explain the process of connectivity
with sql server and to execute stored procedure 
by using json.Thanks in Advance.
Regards saqib

Comment: what you have tried so far ? and btw it's not jason. it's JSON

Comment: Put some efforts by self first

Comment: I'm not really sure how it's possible to execute a stored procedure using a text format for representing data.  Perhaps you want to use JSON in conjunction with something else?

Answer (score 2):

`JSON` won't execute a command.  It is merely a way of storing data in a text-based form easily readable for developers.  You will need to create a `WebMethod` if you want to use `JSON` to store the values of the `DropDown`s or return the data into `DropDown`s.  The following code shows how to create a Web Service and use `JSON` in order to return results from the database.  You would use the `DataContractJsonSerializer` class to also read `JSON`.  This example came from [`Using JSON with ASP.NET 3.5`](http://dotnetslackers.com/articles/aspnet/Using-JSON-With-ASPNET-35.aspx#Using_JSON_with_AJAX_Enabled_ASP.NET_Web_Service)

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Runtime.Serialization;
using System.ServiceModel;
using System.ServiceModel.Activation;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Runtime.Serialization.Json;
[ServiceContract(Namespace = "")]
[AspNetCompatibilityRequirements(RequirementsMode = AspNetCompatibilityRequirementsMode.Allowed)]
public class ProductService
{   
 [OperationContract]    
 public string GetProductDetailsByProductID(int productID)
 {
   Product prod = new Product();        
   string connectionString = 
     "server=localhost;uid=sa;pwd=thiru;database=AdventureWorks;";
   using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
   {
     string sql = "Select Name, ProductNumber from Production.Product " +
       " Where ProductID = " + productID.ToString();
     connection.Open();
     SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(sql, connection); 
     SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();
     while (reader.Read())
     {
       prod.Name = reader["Name"].ToString();
       prod.ProductNumber = reader["ProductNumber"].ToString();
       prod.ProductID = productID;
     }
    }
    MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream();
    DataContractJsonSerializer serializer = new 
      DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(Product));
    serializer.WriteObject(stream, prod);
    stream.Position = 0;
    StreamReader streamReader = new StreamReader(stream);
    return streamReader.ReadToEnd();        
  } 
}
[DataContract]
public class Product
{
    [DataMember]
    public int ProductID;
    [DataMember]
    public string Name;
    [DataMember]
    public string ProductNumber;
}
```